# Magento installation probleme on windows 7 / wamp

Tags: magento

Getting following error in Windows7 using Wamp 2.2 during magento-1.7.0.2 installation .

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.

i have already ran magento-check.php (in magento folder on my localhost) and its shows that the server fulfills all the required things for the magento installation.
plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the apache error log. If problem persists, try to re-install it.